# Linkdemand warning in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to get the version of Iexplorer.exe in my DLL.However i get this warning every time

Warning 1   CA2122 : Microsoft.Security : 'ApCkr.IEavailable()' calls into 'FileVersionInfo.FileMajorPart.get()' which has a LinkDemand. By making this call, 'FileVersionInfo.FileMajorPart.get()' is indirectly exposed to user code. Review the following call stack that might expose a way to circumvent security protection:

After loads of searching in MSDN (security permissions) and falgs,i still cannot get any idea of how i am going to get rid of this error. i tried

```
SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
```

But couldn't get it to work either

Any help would be much appreciated

```
    #region IExplore

    public string IEavailable()
    {
        bool IEversion;

        FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("C:\\program files\\\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
        FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("C:\\program files\\\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
        int a = myFileVersionInfo.FileMajorPart;
        if (a < 8)
        {
            IEversion = false;
        }
        else
        {
            IEversion = true;
        }
        return IEversion.ToString();
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Hold on a minute here. Before you attempt to eliminate the warning: **did you do a thorough security review?** Did you ensure that the indirect exposure of the link-demanded method is safe even when called indirectly by partially-trusted code? The warning is trying to keep you safe. Don't ask "how do I turn off this smoke detector?" until you've determined that its a false alarm; turning off a correctly functioning smoke detector that is going off is a good way to burn down the building.

Comment: @EricLippert I'll look into that.Besides i don't think a simple file version query poses any major threats

Answer (score 7):

This is the link demand attribute on the FileVersionInfo class it is talking about:

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Name="FullTrust")]
```

This is documented well in the MSDN article, but not always easy to recurse from the FxCop message.  I personally find Reflector quite handy to sort this out.

A link demand is a very cheap demand to check at runtime.  It is performed at just-in-time compile time, just once and only checks the permissions of the immediate caller.  The possible security leak occurs because your property getter might be called by *other* code, later.  Such code won't get the same demand check because your property is missing the attribute and is already jitted.  You have to apply the same security attribute.

This will only be a problem when such code runs *without* FullTrust.  Kinda hard to come up with a scenario like that, you would have to create your own sandbox and expose your property to such sandboxed code.  In case you're wondering about the security implications of being able to check the version of a DLL: knowing exactly what version of a DLL is used by a program is rather important to figure out an attack vector.

FxCop is not nearly smart enough to detect such scenarios.  It is really the kind of tool that just emits warnings of things you *might* have overlooked.  And you probably did.  CAS is otherwise quite hard to comprehend, I struggle mightily myself.  And everybody else, it got deprecated in .NET 4 because of that, replaced by a sandboxing model for security.  Wise move, security that's incomprehensible is insecure.

Answer (score -1):

That isn't an error- its a warning.  The documentation explaining what a LinkDemand is is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzsc022c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: MSDN examples are beyond me.Could you please explain it in simple wors